# Presto SQL Map to Columns

Tags: sql, group-by, sum, presto

I am trying to create some columns from a map, can someone help?
My query is this:

```
     select
           multimap_agg(produtos,amount) products  ,"seller" seller from
     self_service_data.self_inside_field_sales
     where pipeline = '[IS] Closer Pipeline'
     group by 2
```

I have this kind of result:

[image: My Table]

I am trying get a table with small groups with:

```
Seller, Number of Products (A+B) sold,   sum(amount), Number of Products sold(C+D),  sum(amount)
```

Comment: Please show us sample data from the original table (not the results of your query) and expected results, as tabular text.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see the point for using maps. From the structure of your expected results, it looks like simple aggregation would get the job done:

```
select
    seller,
    produtos,
    count(*) no_produtos,
    sum(amount) sum_amount
from self_service_data.self_inside_field_sales
where pipeline = '[IS] Closer Pipeline'
group by seller, produtos
```

Comment: I use maps because i have small groups that i want to see, Ex: Seller, Count(Product A+B), Sum( Amount1), Count( Product C+D),...... i can make this product with your query + joins but it very costly (+7 joins). Using maps i was hoping to reduce this. i ll remake the question, sorry if not was misleading